# How to install Epson L375 printer in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: printing, epson, lsb-release

I have installed now Ubuntu 16.04 in my computer, but the installation of my Epson Ecotank L375 printer failed. I can not find the driver of the printer and there is not a lsb file for the drivers installation. What could I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/763157/ubuntu-16-04-installing-epson-driver-fails-on-lsb-3-2

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do is run this command before adding a printer and the printer is recognized immediately

```
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-escpr
```

The solution was provided on http://askubuntu.com/questions/763157/ubuntu-16-04-installing-epson-driver-fails-on-lsb-3-2 as pointed out by @AntoniosHadjigeorgalis.

Comment: This also work with Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

Add Ubuntu Trusty repository via system>software update>other software install lsb and then remove the repository. You can install the driver. This is the only way now till a solution is brought up by Canonical. The lsb files work in Xenial and even if one does an update from Trusty to Xenial with lsb installed, they are left behind and fully functional.

Comment: could you please specify or write a more detailed explanation please? I recently installed Ubuntu and couldn't follow all of you steps. Many thanks beforehand.